# Select last record from database on the basis of primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to retrieve last record from database table.  My query is as below:

```
Select AppointmentDate from tbAppointment where MID=@MID
```

MID is employee id code and primary key is ID.
Since primary key(in my case) is integer and auto incremented on each record insertion, I am trying to get last record on the basis of primary key as last record will have primary key with highest value as compared to other records.

But I am not able to formulate how to give condition specifying primary key with highest value. I need to add primary key contraint like below:

Select AppointmentDate from tbAppointment where MID=@MID AND (highest primary key value)

Comment: I was thinking same thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 AppointmentDate
FROM   tbAppointment
WHERE  MID = @MID
ORDER  BY ID DESC
```

Comment: this is nice , better than using max function

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Top 1     
AppointmentDate from tbAppointment     
where MID=@MID
Order By ID Desc
```

This worked for me, It helped me to retrieve last row inserted into database table. Thanks to    James :)

Comment: I've fixed the code in the other answer so this one can be deleted now as it doesn't add anything.

Comment: Yeah surely  if it adds to content quality

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  AppointmentDate
FROM   tbAppointment where Mid = (select max(MID) from tbAppointment)
```